# C++ cut char pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, char

Is it possible to cut char pointer to remove packet header?

To avoid the loops:

```
Decryptor dec;
char * datae = new char[_packet[0] - 8];
char * decrypted;
for(int i = 0;i<_packet[0] - 8;i++)
{
    datae[i] = _packet[8+i];
}
decrypted = dec.decrypt(datae, _packet[0]-8);
```

Comment: You could pass `_packet + 8` into your `dec.decrypt()` function. Read up on "pointer arithmetic"

Comment: `std::copy(_packet + 8, _packet + _packet[0] - 8, datae);` (In case you really want to copy the data [like the loop does], and not just change the pointer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Decryptor dec;
char * decrypted = dec.decrypt(_packet + 8, _packet); // _packet[0] - 8 is going to give you the value of the character at _packet[0] minus 8, which is not likely to be what you want.
```